# 'Lost' tag is meaningless

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

[This is on 8 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lost), and I just saw it used as recently as today.  This seems like the definition of a meta tag to me and should probably go away, yes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And so, we come to the end of another meta tag.

Will it ever return? Let's well hope not.

Should it ever try to peek through, be sure to edit it out and clean up the post while you're doing so.

Comment: smells like freedom